# Updating child value in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to update a child value called "PhotoGallery" in a child called "users".

How do I rewrite this code to do so.

```
func registerDatabase(id: String, url: [String: AnyObject]) {

        //Create a database reference
        let userRef = self.databaseRef.child("users").childByAutoId().child(id)

        userRef.updateChildValues(["PhotoGallery":url]) {(error, ref) in

            if error != nil{
                print("Error registering Firebase database: \(error)")

                return
            }

            print("Successfully stored in DB")
        }
    }

    func removeSpecialCharsFromString(text: String) -> String {
        let validChars: Set<Character> = Set("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890".characters)

        return String(text.characters.filter{validChars.contains($0)})
    }
```

Comment: Your *parent* node is users, which has a child created by childByAutoId, who has a child *id* (a string) who then has a child PhotoGallery which is a key whose value is a string *url*.

Comment: you can not update child value by childByAutoId(). This will create a new child.

Comment: how do I then update this specific child of a current user ????

Answer (score 1):

A setValue will do it since you are creating the child node on the fly with childByAutoId.

```
let userChildRef = self.databaseRef.child("users").childByAutoId()
let photoRef = userChildRef.child("id").child("PhotoGallery")
photoRef.setValue(url)
```

results in

```
users
   -Yuhusn9asijasd
      id
       PhotoGallery: "www.someurl.com"
```

note I left photoRef as a separate let to make it more readable since userChildRef now refers to all of the children of that user

```
let nameRef = userChildRef.child("name")
nameRef.setValue("Gilligan")

let hatColorRef = userChildRef.child("hat")
hatColorRef.setValue("White")

let shirtColorRef = userChildRef.child("shirt")
shirtColorRef.setValue("Red")


users
   -Yuhusn9asijasd
      id:
        PhotoGallery: "www.someurl.com"
      name: "Gilligan"
      hat: "White"
      shirt: "Red"
```

Comment: Thanks, but that does not update the specific child of the current user. It only creates at new child by auto id

Comment: @CarstenHøvsgaard The code posted in your question uses childByAutoId, which means it will not, for any reason update a child of a specific user. Every time that function is called it creates a new child node, and therefore there wouldn't be anything to update since a new child node would be empty.